# SPFx monorepo with shared typescript code

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, spfx, typescript

Tasks are:

- Having multiple similar sibling folders each contains spfx projects with one webpart, and ability to develop each separately and build each own .sppkg file for a separate deployment.
- Having another sibling folder that contains shared typescript code that can be imported by webparts .ts classes (not libraries, just ts code)

We have a monorepo with next folders structure:

```
WebPartOne
  src
  tsconfig.json
  ...

WebPartTwo
  src
  tsconfig.json
  ...

Common
  src
  tsconfig.json
  ...
```

WebPartOne, WebPartTwo are identical, the only difference is in their webparts themselves.
Common folder contains some typescript code (common react components, common models, common services).

Workflow without common resources: starting local workbench with

```
gulp clean && gulp build && gulp serve
```

which gives a normal compiled lib structure

```
webparts
  webpartone
    webpartone.webpart.manifest.json
    webpartone.webpart.js
    webpartone.webpart.d.ts
index.d.ts
index.js
...
```

all good and working fine as expected

Workflow with common resources: importing shared code like this

```
import { IHttpParams } from '../../../../Common/src/models/http.model';
```

and when we try to run

```
gulp clean && gulp build && gulp serve
```

lib folder structure became this

```
webparts
  webpartone
    --- empty --- there is no more webpartone.webpart.js
WebPartOne
  src
    ... it all goes here
Common
  src
    models
      ... compiled imported model
```

so the folder structure breaks and SPFx can no longer import all necessary files from lib and gives

Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve `'C:\Users\localuser\Documents\Projects\CCP\FE\WebPartOne\lib\webparts\webpartone\webpartone.webpart.js' in 'C:\Users\localuser\Documents\Projects\CCP\FE\WebPartOne'`

This behavior is expected as ts looks at farther parent folder and then build out folder structures relying on that. But can it be avoided somehow?
We tried to configure tsconfig.json-s but with no luck, the thing is that SPFx is building via gulp, and i guess configuring ts here is a bit tricky, unlike a regular ts project.

There are some articles about how build common files to a library, then import them, but we need to have just imports, even if a code will be duplicated in each .sppkg-s.
I have spent couple of days on this and no luck (

I appreciate any help.
Thank you!